# Problems with running GTK3+ Python GUI for a web crawler

Tags: python, pygtk

My program is a Python based Web crawler that pulls data through the terminal commands on Linux distributions(Ubuntu 14 used). 
Now ever since I implemented a GT3+ GUI for it I got the following error:

> /usr/bin/python3.4 /home/dipeshwar/Documents/WebsiteScanner/main.py Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>
> "/home/dipeshwar/Documents/WebsiteScanner/main.py", line 81, in
>   button_clicked
>       gather_info(self.name, self.url)   File "/home/dipeshwar/Documents/WebsiteScanner/main.py", line 44, in
>   gather_info
>       domain = get_domain_name(url)   File "/home/dipeshwar/Documents/WebsiteScanner/domain.py", line 16, in
>   get_domain_name
>       domain = get_tld(url)   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/tld/utils.py", line 161, in
>   get_tld
>       url = url.lower() AttributeError: 'Entry' object has no attribute 'lower'
>   Here is my code. Could you tell me why its giving me that error?
>   In the get_doman_name function Im just using 'tld' module in Python to get the Top Level Domain.

Regards

```
from gi.repository import Gtk
# import statement for GUI
from general import *
from whois import *
from domain import *
from ipadd import *
from nmap import *
from robots_txt import *
# these import statements get all the variables from other modules of this program

ROOT_DIR = 'Output'
create_dir(ROOT_DIR)
# Checks if directory is created or not, if not, the program creates it

def create_report(name, url, domain, ipadd, nmap, robots_txt, whois): # or def create_report(name, full_url, domain, ipadd, nmap, robots_txt, whois): ?

    project_dir = ROOT_DIR + '/' + name
    create_dir(project_dir)
    write_file(project_dir + '/full_url.txt', url) # or full_url ?
    write_file(project_dir + '/domain.txt', domain)
    write_file(project_dir + '/ipadd.txt', ipadd)
    write_file(project_dir + '/nmap.txt', nmap)
    write_file(project_dir + '/robots_txt.txt', robots_txt)
    write_file(project_dir + '/whois.txt', whois)



def gather_info(name, url):
    domain = get_domain_name(url)
    ipadd = get_ip_address(url)
    nmap = get_nmap(ipadd)
    robots_txt = get_robots_txt(url)
    whois = get_whois(url)
    create_report(name, url, domain, ipadd, nmap, robots_txt, whois)


class MainWindow(Gtk.Window):


    def __init__(self):
        Gtk.Window.__init__(self, title="Reconnaissance Web-Scanner")
        self.set_border_width(30)
        self.set_size_request(300, 200)

        # Layout of window
        vbox = Gtk.Box(orientation=Gtk.Orientation.VERTICAL, spacing=8)
        self.add(vbox)

        # Inputs
        self.name = Gtk.Entry()
        self.name.set_text("Enter name of website here:")
        vbox.pack_start(self.name, True, True, 0)

        self.url = Gtk.Entry()
        self.url.set_text("Enter URL of website here:")
        vbox.pack_start(self.url, True, True, 0)


        # Button
        self.button = Gtk.Button(label="Scan Website")
        self.button.connect("clicked", self.button_clicked)
        vbox.pack_start(self.button, True, True, 0)

    # when user clicks the button    
    def button_clicked(self, widget):
        gather_info(self.name, self.url)
        # put exec code here
```

Answer (score 0):

`self.name` and `self.url` are both `Gtk.Entry`s and not strings. So you have to change your code to:

```
    def button_clicked(self, widget):
        gather_info(self.name.get_text(), self.url.get_text())
```